# How to check a string while entering it in MySQL DB for characters in the beginning by DEFAULT?

Tags: mysql, default-value

I want to create a table where i want to list some books on different subject. I want to include first letter of the topic in the book id. For example, books on mathematics will contain 'M', literature will contain 'C'.
I had the idea to use something like 
`CREATE TABLE book (id VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT LIKE 'M%', book_name VARCHAR(10))`
But, it's showing error.

### Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

> A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "'M%'" at position
>   46)
>   Blockquote
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 71)

### SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE book (id VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT LIKE 'M%', book_name VARCHAR(10))
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIKE 'M%', book_name VARCHAR(10))' at line 1

Comment: Not sure what you want, but you probably want a trigger. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You have tagged two different flavors of SQL here...

Comment: and the syntax is wrong. I suppose you want to add constraint on the table. TO accept a particular set of values for book. But that is not default. Default value can be simple text. That is why usage of '%M' using which you want all words ending with M is wrong.

Comment: If this is a MySQL question, you should un-tag "SQLServer" which is completely different

Answer (score 0):

The query usage of default is wrong. You can have only fixed text in default.
Also I am not sure if you want text ending with M in ID or book_name, but looking at the query I am assuming it is id.

You need to use constraint to control the values allowed for id. Correct query with constraint will be as below

```
CREATE TABLE book (id VARCHAR(5), book_name VARCHAR(10), CONSTRAINT check_book_name CHECK (id like '%M'))
```

Next thing is

> I want to include first letter of the topic in the book id.

to do that you can only add constraint as check but you can control this only through your insert statement.

My suggestion formulate the data set. Then simply create table. Based on your dataset add constraint on the table. Add pre-insert validations. This pre-insert validation would be along with the app or code executing the insert statement.